# Efficient java map for values.contains(object) in O(1)?

Tags: java, performance, dictionary

I've started writing a tool for modelling graphs (nodes and edges, both represented by objects, not adjacency matrices or simply numbers) recently to get some practice in software development next to grad school. I'd like a node to know its neighbors and the edges it's incident with. An obvious way to do this would be to take a HashSet and a HashSet. What I would like to do however is have a method

```
Node_A.getEdge(Node B)
```

that returns the edge between nodes A and B in O(1). I was thinking of doing this by replacing the two HashSets mentioned above by using one HashMap that maps the neighbors to the edges that connect a node with its neighbors. For example, calling

```
Node_A.hashmap.get(B)
```

should return the edge that connects A and B. My issue here is whether there's a way to have

```
HashMap.keySet().contains(Node A);
HashMap.values().contains(Edge e);
```

both work in O(1)? If that isn't the case with the standard libraries, are there implementations that will give me constant time for add, remove, contains, size for keySet() and values()?

Comment: Both `keySet()` and `entrySet()` already has `O(1)` complexity provided that you have implemented `hashcode` and `equals()` correctly. Only `valueSet` does has `O(n)` complexity.

Comment: @AmitD I mistyped, I meant values() instead of entrySet(). Do you mean the Set I get back from keySet() has add, remove, contains, size in O(1) or do you mean that the method keySet() itself runs in O(1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not to over-think this.
E.g. you are saying you get the edge between A and B by `Node_A.getEdge(Node B)`. But normally it is the **A->B**-information that **IS** considered the edge. (So you are requiring the information you should be retrieving.)

You say you want O(1), understandably, and obviously storing an adjacency-matrix will only give you O(n), so you cannot use that; but already the second-most obvious choice *storing a list of adjacent nodes within each node object* will give you what you want. (Note: this is different from having a global adjacency-list which would give you O(n)).

Comment: Actually using an adjacency matrix would give me O(1) time to see whether there is an edge between two specific nodes, but you are of course correct regarding checking for the neighbors of a node. My trouble mainly comes from the fact that I want to have objects representing the edges since later on they are supposed to be assigned arbitrary attributes, which would become troublesome if the information about which nodes are connected by edges is only implied. I probably am overthinking this since all I would need to do would be use a HashSet and HashMap, but hey memory isn't cheap :P

Comment: With the O(n) adjacency matrix i mean the time needed to retrieve all neighbors of a node (not check whether two nodes are mutual neighbors). Yes, storing edges as objects is ok if you need additional attributes, just make each node have a list of edge-objects.

Comment: @G.Bach actually, it might be more efficient to simply store the connected nodes in the edge (in which case the `contains(edge)` implementation is trivial), since you'd have an extra object field per node-edge pair, instead of a `Map.Entry` (an `Object` + 2 object fields) + a `Map` (an `Object`, an object field, a `Map.Entry` array) / n edges.

Answer (score 1):

As AmitD said HashSet and HashMap alredy have constant times for for contains, get and put. For `HashMap.valueSet().contains(Edge e)` case you may try to look at [HashBiMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashBiMap.html) in Google Guava library.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at this; at first glance it looks like it won't be what I'm looking for since I'm basically trying to minimize space requirements, and using a data structure that's backed by two HashMaps is more expensive than what I currently have.

Comment: @G.Bach it's not more expensive, since a HashSet is _also_ backed by a HashMap.

Comment: @FrankPavageau Ah, I was not aware of that - I'll have to look at Zvezdochet's recommendation more in depth then!